# Python create global files

Tags: python

I made a library in python for myself, I regularly update it and don't want to go inside every project and update the folder

What is a more efficient way of doing this? Is there a way that I only need the file once and can easily update it? (the lib must remain private and cannot be shared with the public)

Comment: why does every project need to be updated? this is what versioning is for

Comment: I simply need it, not gonna update all files every time i changed something

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own private PyPi repository, for example in [JFrog](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/PyPI+Repositories).

After you upload your library you can just add her name in the requirements.txt file with the latest version and install it with pip.